# I got an error while doing js calculations

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, math

```js
  const api_url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD'
  async function getprice() {
      const response = await fetch(api_url);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      return parseFloat(data) // we return the price as float
  }

  const calculate = async () => {
      const price = await getPrice() // we call price function and save it in price variable 
      const result = price * balance      
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <spam id="price">-</spam> // here to be output
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the price for BTC from this URL and then multiply it with the balance I got in my wallet the code Is this

```
  const api_url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD'
  async function getprice() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  // document.getElementById('data').textContent = JSON.stringify(data.USD)
  }

  getprice();

  let x = {data} * {balance}
```

but I get an error.

Comment: There's no error in the code you share, maybe it's on the use of curly brackets (?) in this line ` let x = {data} * {balance / 1e8} {computer.getChain()}
` that aren't suppose to be there. If you can provide further information so we can give you a abetter answer.

Comment: i want to get price and multiply with balance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will answer your questions as you had provide insufficient information so we can reproduce your issue.

#### Edit:

With the snippet you provided I attach you a working snippet, I don't know where are you getting you balance so I used a random number as example. Also `spam` element has a typo it had to be `span`. Hope it helps you.

```js
 const api_url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD'
 
 const getPrice = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(api_url);
      const data = await response.json();
      return parseFloat(data.USD) // we return the price as float
  }
  
  const balance = 53 // IDK where are you getting this value I just used a random number as example

  const calculate = async () => {
      const price = await getPrice() // we call price function and save it in price variable 
      const result = price * balance
      document.querySelector('#price').innerText = result; // Log into span element
  }
  
  calculate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <span id="price">-</span> // here to be output
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is obviously you line of code that's not working, I can't help you as I don't know where are you getting that portion of code that has a weird syntax, you are getting an error in the curly brackets, declaring an object but trying to divide its property. About objects you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#:~:text=The%20Object%20type%20represents%20one,the%20object%20initializer%20%2F%20literal%20syntax.

Comment: nvm i fixed anyways thank you for your help <3